# Can't serve font files from public directory - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

I have a .woff font file that's currently sitting in **app/assets/fonts/myfont.woff**, where it gets served from **myapp.com/assets/myfont.woff**.

I want to move it from the asset directory to the public directory at **public/fonts/myfont.woff**, but for some reason when I try to access it there at **myapp.com/fonts/myfont.woff** I get a routing error:

> No route matches [GET] "/fonts/myfont.woff"

It must be a MIME type issue, as I can serve a text file from the same location just fine- but I can't understand how to fix it, especially since the same extension gets served out of the assets directory without a problem.

Comment: AFAIK, Shouldn't the directory be `public/fonts` instead of `app/public/fonts` ?

Comment: Have you included the file in your config's `config.autoload_paths`?

Comment: @SampritiPanda - You're right- that was a misstype

Comment: @RichPeck - Not sure what you mean- files I place in public folder are always served automatically, without any special configuration. For example, if I drop a text file in the same spot (e.g. **public/fonts/test.txt**) it will be served no problem. It's only the **.woff** files that don't serve.

Comment: it looks like your web server is not serving the .woff file but passign the request to the rails server, you need to configure your web server to serve all files from /public/fonts before reaching your rails server, do you use apache? nginx? something else?

Comment: @arieljuod - My remote setup is Heroku with Unicorn Rails server (Heroku web server = nginx I believe?) but the strange thing is that it's not serving locally either when I run Unicorn w Foreman on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server config http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html.

I guess the problem is that your web server is not configured to server .woff files from /public but only for /public/assets, then it passes the request to rails but rails on production doesn't serve static assets by default (config.serve_static_assets = false on environments/production.rb).

So, go to your web server's config file and check the rules in there, I guess you are missing some .woff somewhere.

Anyway, why do you want to move fonts to /public/fonts? those files are assets and /public/assets/fonts is the best place for them.

EDIT: I guess you have the same problem locally when you run unicorn and your rails server in production mode, you would need to configure unicorn too to serve static assets since rails won't handle them